# Iterators of forward_list C++

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, containers, forward-list

I have a forward_list and I need to keep the iterators of the elements of the list in order to erase them if they satisfy some properties.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include<forward_list>

int main(){

std::forward_list<int> mylist = {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70};
std::vector<std::forward_list<int>::iterator> iter;

for(std::forward_list<int>::iterator it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it){
    iter.push_back(it);
}

mylist.erase_after(iter[2]);
iter.erase(iter.begin()+2);


mylist.erase_after(iter[2]);
return 1;
}
```

The second `mylist.erase_after(iter[2]);` does not delete any element. I observed that I have loose access to the 3rd element of my list (after erasing), to access to this element I added the following code before the second `mylist.erase_after(iter[2]);`.

```
int i=0;
for(auto it= mylist.begin();i<=2;++it,++i){
    if(i==2)
    iter[2]=it;
}
```

Is this the best way to get access after deleting an element of the list?

Answer (score 1):

`mylist.erase_after(iter[2])` invalidates any iterators referring to the element being erased  - including `iter[3]`. After `iter.erase(iter.begin()+2);`, the invalid iterator that used to be in `iter[3]` is now in `iter[2]`. Finally, `mylist.erase_after(iter[2]);` exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an invalid iterator.

Recall that `erase_after(some_iter)` doesn't remove the element that `some_iter` points to, but the element following it (hence "after").

Comment: yes, I agree with you, now I am using  now `std::list` and the manipulation is working. I wanted to avoid doubly linked lists, but this seems not to work with `std::forward_list`.

Comment: @user108724 Well, it can be made to work with `std::forward_list` with some effort - you just have to be very careful which elements are removed by which iterators. You have to constantly remind yourself that manipulating a node of a singly-linked list requires a pointer to the previous node, not this node, and design accordingly. Working with `std::list` is certainly much easier and more natural.